# pandas dataframe convert values in array of objects

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert the below pandas data frame

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [5,6]], columns=['10+', '20+'], index=['A', 'B'])
data.index.name = 'City'
data.columns.name= 'Age Group'
print data

Age Group  10+  20+
City               
A            1    2
B            5    6
```

in to an array of dictionaries, like

```
[
 {'Age Group': '10+', 'City': 'A', 'count': 1},
 {'Age Group': '20+', 'City': 'A', 'count': 2},
 {'Age Group': '10+', 'City': 'B', 'count': 5},
 {'Age Group': '20+', 'City': 'B', 'count': 6}
]
```

I am able to get the above expected result using the following loops

```
result = []
cols_name = data.columns.name
index_names = data.index.name
for index in data.index:
    for col in data.columns:
        result.append({cols_name: col, index_names: index, 'count': data.loc[index, col]})
```

Is there any better ways of doing this? Since my original data will be having large number of records, using for loops will take more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for reshape and last [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
print (data.stack().reset_index(name='count'))
  City Age Group  count
0    A       10+      1
1    A       20+      2
2    B       10+      5
3    B       20+      6

print (data.stack().reset_index(name='count').to_dict(orient='records'))
[
  {'Age Group': '10+', 'City': 'A', 'count': 1}, 
  {'Age Group': '20+', 'City': 'A', 'count': 2}, 
  {'Age Group': '10+', 'City': 'B', 'count': 5}, 
  {'Age Group': '20+', 'City': 'B', 'count': 6}
]
```

Comment: Sure, no problem.